# Ordering axis of seaborn.countplot

Tags: python, seaborn, countplot

I'm plotting day of week frequencies from a list of strings `dayWeek`, where `set(dayWeek) = {'Mon', 'Sun', 'Tue', 'Sat', 'Fri', 'Wed', 'Thu'}`

It seems to just order the columns by the order that they appear in. How can I change the order to `'Sun'...'Sat'` instead?

[image]

Comment: If you have a look at the documentation, you may note that there is a parameter called `order` that seems relevant: http://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.countplot.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

figured it out:

```
k = ['Sun','Mon','Tue','Wed','Thu','Fri','Sat']
dayWeek = sorted(dayWeek, key=k.index)
```

Answer (score 7):

You can use the order parameter of countplot like this:

```
sns.countplot(y='DOW',order=['Sun','Mon','Tue','Wed','Thu','Fri','Sat'], data=df, palette='viridis')
```

where `DOW` is my `dayofweek` column.

I also noticed that by not mentioning a day, you can omit that day being displayed in the chart.